# Three divs next to each other, third fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have three divs, all should be next to each other but the third one needs to be fixed at his position. I tried using right:0, float:right but in these cases the third div doesn't stick to the other two, instead it sticks to the right browser side, which is not what I want. Do I have to javascript move it depending on calculated browser window width or is there a html/css (perhaps bootstrap) way to do it?

I have following html:

```
        <div id="sub-container">
            <div id="left">
                {left}
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                {content}
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                {right}
            </div>
        </div>
```

And such css:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    top:$topbarHeight;
    width:$leftWidth;
    position:relative;
    margin:2px auto;
    min-height:600px;
    z-index:1;
 }

#right {
    width:$rightWidth;
    height:604px;
    top:$topbarHeight;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#sub-container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    max-width:724px;
    margin:auto;
    clear: both;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    top:$topbarHeight;
    float:left;
    max-width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the right div's position to absolute rather than fixed, it will move to the right distance respective to the subcontainer rather than to the browser.

Comment: The third div needs to stay fixed, so, changing it to absolute doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I'll have to think it through more but it seems like you're going to have to use javascript to achieve this. Off the top of my head, doing some sort of scroll spy for when the parent div is on the screen and then adjusting the third divs top value as the scroll happens would achieve this. This would be using the absolute positioning still.

Position fixed would have to be run similar with a javascript function of some sort, but with also checking for the parent offset top and right to add to the measurements for the third div's right and top.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them all `float: left` and then get the right one, `position: absolute` and the middle one, `position: relative`. Then it will stick to the right of middle one and you can get it, its position.

Comment: If I change the position to absolute it is no longer fixed, I need it to be also fixed and also stick to the content not to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#right {
    right:50%;
    height:604px;
    transform: translateX(312px); /*half of your container*/
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: 10px;
    top:0; /*or however far from the top you want it */
}
```

when you get to your break #point unset the transform and and set right to 0 or however far you want it from the edge.